# SQL Server table to nested xml file

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, xquery

I have a table like this:

```
Action Action2  Name    Action3 Batch
--------------------------------------
add      PL    Steve    add      1
add      PL    Steve    add      3
add      PL    Steve    add      4
add      PL    Steve    add      5
add      PL    Steve    add      1
add      PL    Steve    add      3
add      PL    Steve    add      4
add      PL    Steve    add      5
```

and need to turn it into an XML document like this:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Check [this](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/converting-string-data-to-xml-and-xml-to-string-data/) out.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I did recreate the [test data](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b94ab864890ba139941efd71d4d47e6d) so I figure I could share that.

Comment: This posting doesn't contain enough information. You need to save the XML to a file from SQL Server? Please edit the posting and provide additional information or you will get downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Isaac for the data script!

`for <List> elements in <Branch> node, like <Branch><List/><List/></Branch>:`

```
CREATE TABLE #mytable
(
   Action  VARCHAR(10),
   Action2 VARCHAR(10),
   Name    VARCHAR(50),
   Action3 VARCHAR(10),
   Batch   INT
);

INSERT INTO #mytable(Action,Action2,Name,Action3,Batch) 
VALUES 
('add','PL','Steve','add',1),
('add','PL','Steve','add',3),
('add','PL','Steve','add',4),
('add','PL','Steve','add',5),
('add','PL','Steve','add',1),
('add','PL','Steve','add',3),
('add','PL','Steve','add',4),
('add','PL','Steve','add',5);


INSERT INTO #mytable(Action,Action2,Name,Action3,Batch) 
VALUES 
('update','PL','John','insert',5),
('update','PL','Paul','insert',1),
('update','PL','Chris','delete',3),
('update','PL','Mary','update',4),
('update','PL','Jane','delete',5);


select a1.Action as '@Action', s.brancexml as '*'
from
(
select distinct Action
from #mytable
) as a1
cross apply 
(
    select
    (
        select a2.Action2 AS '@Action', a2.Name as '@Name', x.listxml as     '*'
        from
    (
        select distinct Action2, Name
        from #mytable AS b
        where b.Action = a1.Action
    ) AS a2
    cross apply
    (
        select
        (
            select distinct c.Action3 as '@Action', c.Batch as '@Batch'
            from #mytable AS c
            where c.Action = a1.Action AND c.Action2 = a2.Action2 AND c.Name = a2.Name
            for xml path('List'), type
        ) AS listxml
    ) as x
    for xml path('Brance'), type
    ) as brancexml
) as s
for xml path('Start'), root('Entries'), type
```

Comment: This is a good solution, +1 from my side. Just a tiny hint: `GROUP BY` is in most cases better than `DISTINCT`. For this issue I think, that nested, correlated sub-selects are much easier to read than this approach with `APPLY`...

Answer (score 0):

You've got a solution already, but this might be put a bit simpler:

```
CREATE TABLE #mytable
(
   Action  VARCHAR(10),
   Action2 VARCHAR(10),
   Name    VARCHAR(50),
   Action3 VARCHAR(10),
   Batch   INT
);

INSERT INTO #mytable(Action,Action2,Name,Action3,Batch) 
VALUES 
('add','PL','Steve','add',1),
('add','PL','Steve','add',3),
('add','PL','Steve','add',4),
('add','PL','Steve','add',5),
('update','PL','John','insert',5),
('update','PL','Paul','insert',1),
('update','PL','Chris','delete',3),
('update','PL','Mary','update',4),
('update','PL','Jane','delete',5);

SELECT mt1.[Action] AS [@Action]
      ,(
        SELECT mt2.Action2 AS [@Action]
              ,mt2.[Name] AS [@Name]
              ,(
                SELECT mt3.Action3 AS [@Action]
                      ,mt3.Batch AS [@Batch]
                FROM #mytable mt3
                WHERE mt3.[Action]=mt1.[Action]
                  AND mt3.Action2=mt2.Action2
                  AND mt3.[Name]=mt2.[Name]
                FOR XML PATH('List'),TYPE        
               )
        FROM #mytable mt2
        WHERE mt2.[Action]=mt1.[Action]
        GROUP BY mt2.Action2,mt2.[Name]
        FOR XML PATH('Brance'),TYPE
       )
FROM #mytable mt1
GROUP BY mt1.[Action]
FOR XML PATH('Start'),ROOT('Entries');
```

The idea in short:

We use a cascade of correlated sub-queries, each returning one fragment of the nested structure.
Using `,TYPE` will return this as XML, otherwise you would get escaped text.
Using `GROUP BY` allows us to return the nesting data just once.

This won't be very fast... Indexes on the columns used in `WHERE` will help you.